# How do i find the time complexity of a function with a nested for loop with constants

Tags: time-complexity

```
Code(n){
val = n;
int i = 1;
for(i<n^2;i++){
    for(j=1301;j<1922;j++){
        val=val*val*val;
        for(int k=i;k<i^2;k++){
            val=val*k;
}
}
}
}
```

```
i 1 to n^2 is O(n^2)
j 1301 to 1922 is O((n-1)^2*621)
val*val*val is O((n-1)*620)
k i to i^2 is O((n-1)*620*i^2)
val*k is O((n-1)*620*(i-1)^2)
```

So is the time complexity is O(n^2)?
is this right? Can we not include anything smaller than n^2?

Comment: Your reasoning works if `i` is a constant with respect to `n`. But is it?

Answer (score 0):

In your analysis you need to resolve `i`: it cannot be part of your final complexity expression as it is not an input, but a (temporary) loop variable.

You can start by simplifying the code first: The `for` loop with the `j` variable loops a constant number of times, so you can just move the body of the loop out of it so it runs only once: this doesn't impact the complexity. As `val` is an `int`, we may assume that the multiplications run in constant time, and we can also omit those.

The following code thus has the same complexity:

```
Code(int n) {
    int val = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n*n; i++) {
        for(int k = i; k < i*i; k++) {
            val++;
        }
    }
}
```

If we only had the inner loop, and a given , it would have a time complexity of O(²).

As  varies from 1 to ², we have:

O(1² + 2² + 3² + ... + (−1)²)

This is a [square pyramidal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number). If for a moment we define  as −1, this sum is:

(+1)(2+1) / 6

So it is O(<sup>3</sup>), which is O(<sup>6</sup>)